# Java: plugin install for freemind, get : NoClassDefFoundError org/objectweb/asm/Opcodes

Tags: java, plugins

I am using freemind 0.9 on Ubuntu 12.04, and trying to install a plugin written with "groovy", from 
http://blog.icare3d.org/2011/02/writing-phd-thesis-using-freemind-and.html

I installed freemind, freemind-plugins-script, put manually (and edited) the grrovy srcipt, edited  plugins/ScriptingEngine.xml as described in the link. The plugin is recognised as I can access through the menu, but clicking on it has no effect.

I realise in the terminal there is an error:

```
STDERR: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" 
STDERR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/Opcodes
STDERR:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
STDERR:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
STDERR:     at         java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
STDERR:     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
STDERR:     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
```

My understanding is that I am missing a java component? Is this correct? Or is it that that component is not updated (I note I have grrovy 1.9 while 2.3 seems there)?

If so, how can I locate it? I saw some libasm-java libraries, installed a bunch of them (libasm-dev, libasm-java, libasm1, libasm2-java, libasm2-java, libasm3-java) but still the same error. Interestingly, I note that objectweb/asm/Opcode is mentioned in [libasm2-java-doc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pt/lucid/all/libasm2-java-doc/filelist) but not in libasm2-java

Or maybe the library is correctly installed, but it is the plugin/freemind that does not locate it correctly?

As I don't know anything about Java, any hint would be most appreciated! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe the library is correctly installed, but it is the plugin/freemind that does not locate it correctly?

This is the case, I guess.
For me it works if I start freemind in terminal in the follownig way:

```
ADD_JARS="/usr/share/java/asm3-all.jar:/usr/share/java/antlrall.jar" DEBUG=1 freemind
```